# nginx not starting on boot

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

What do I do when

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

displays

```
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/nginx already exist.
```

yet nginx still doesn't start on reboot?

Comment: it is default behavioour for it to start at boot and that file should be there. Are you sure it does not boot? does ```nginx -t``` show any problems? how about ```service nginx restart```?

Comment: `# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` nginx works fine once I manually start it. Every time I have to ssh in and run `service nginx start` though which obviously isn't ideal.

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu Server 14.04 EC2 AMI on AWS

Comment: Sounds like a really strange problem - might be an idea to use the official [nginx image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00DIF4A6Y/ref=_ptnr_doc_).

Comment: Please take a look on nginx logs. Are you sure nothing binding port 80 on boot? May be you have some other web server that bind port 80 before NGINX tries to start.

Comment: Have the same problem on a Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Droplet on Digital Ocean. No errors in the nginx log file.

Comment: Have the same problem on a Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Droplet on Digital Ocean. But when checking error.log it says: 2016/03/02 01:44:34 [emerg] open() "/path/to/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory). Obviously nginx can not start on boot because necessary directories simply does not exist during boot. In my case this is normal and occurs because it uses mounted directory. Not a nginx or digitalocean or ubuntu issue.. yes the way I'm mounting my paths.

Answer (score 1):

I know this command works on Centos. Not too sure about Ubuntu. Its worth a try though:

> chkconfig nginx on

The syntax is the same for any service like

> chkconfig httpd on

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

first of all check that there are no issues starting nginx in general.

```
vi /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Then check that you can start nginx with the start service and that it is running

```
service nginx start ; ps -ef | grep nginx
```

Then double check that the start script exists and works properly.

```
cd /etc/init.d ; vi nginx*
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The service "service nginx start ; ps -ef | grep nginx" do not work. I installed nginx by using configure make make install, maybe some things did not install the same way as apt-get install nginx? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: yes, its different if you compile from source. This document should help you. http://sharadchhetri.com/2015/02/21/install-nginx-source-code-ubuntu-14-04-lts/